# pandas df.apply unexpectedly changes dataframe inplace

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

From my understanding, pandas.DataFrame.apply does not apply changes inplace and we should use its return object to persist any changes. However, I've found the following inconsistent behavior:

Let's apply a dummy function for the sake of ensuring that the original df remains untouched:

```
>>> def foo(row: pd.Series):
...     row['b'] = '42'

>>> df = pd.DataFrame([('a0','b0'),('a1','b1')], columns=['a', 'b'])
>>> df.apply(foo, axis=1)
>>> df
    a   b
0   a0  b0
1   a1  b1
```

This behaves as expected. However, foo will apply the changes inplace if we modify the way we initialize this df:

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
>>> df2['a'] = ['a0','a1']
>>> df2['b'] = ['b0','b1']
>>> df2.apply(foo, axis=1)
>>> df2
    a   b
0   a0  42
1   a1  42
```

I've also noticed that the above is not true if the columns dtypes are not of type 'object'. Why does apply() behave differently in these two contexts?

Python: 3.6.5

Pandas: 0.23.1

Comment: You are inserting into the `df2['a']`  the values `['a0','b0']`. But in your df2 output the data is different. why?

Comment: edit: updated df2. thanks @roganjosh and Arihant

Comment: Turns out that's nothing to do with the behaviour you're seeing. Nice question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question! I believe the behavior you're seeing is an artifact of the way you use `apply`.

As you correctly indicate, `apply` is not intended to be used to modify a dataframe. However, since `apply` takes an arbitrary function, it doesn't guarantee that applying the function will be idempotent and will not change the dataframe. Here, you've found a great example of that behavior, because your function `foo` attempts to modify the row that it is passed by `apply`.

Using `apply` to modify a row could lead to these side effects. This isn't the best practice.

Instead, consider this idiomatic approach for `apply`. The function `apply` is often used to create a new column. Here's an example of how `apply` is typically used, which I believe would steer you away from this potentially troublesome area:

```
import pandas as pd
# construct df2 just like you did
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
df2['a'] = ['a0','b0']
df2['b'] = ['a1','b1']

df2['b_copy'] = df2.apply(lambda row: row['b'], axis=1) # apply to each row
df2['b_replace'] = df2.apply(lambda row: '42', axis=1) 
df2['b_reverse'] = df2['b'].apply(lambda val: val[::-1]) # apply to each value in b column

print(df2)

# output:
#     a   b b_copy b_replace b_reverse
# 0  a0  a1     a1        42        1a
# 1  b0  b1     b1        42        1b
```

Notice that pandas passed a row or a cell to the function you give as the first argument to `apply`, then stores the function's output in a column of your choice.

If you'd like to modify a dataframe row-by-row, take a look at `iterrows` and `loc` for the most idiomatic route.

Comment: Does this really answer why it doesn't modify the dataframe in the first instance?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe late but I think it may help especially for someone who reach this question.

When we use the `foo` like:

```
def foo(row: pd.Series):
    row['b'] = '42'
```

and then use it in:

```
df.apply(foo, axis=1)
```

we won't expect to occur any change in `df` but it occers. why?

Let's review what happens under the hood:

`apply` function calls `foo` and pass one row to it. As it is not of type of specific `types` in python (like int, float, str, ...) but is an object, so by python rules it is passed by reference not  by value. So it is completely equivalent with the row that is sent by `apply` function.(Equal in values and both points to same block of ram.)
So any change to `row` in `foo` function will changes the `row` - which its type is `pandas.series` and that points to a block of memory that `df.row` resides - immediately.

We can rewrite the `foo`(I name it `bar`) function to not change anything **inplace**. ( by deep copying  `row` that means make another row with same value(s) but on another cell of ram). This is what relly happens when we use `lambda` in `apply` function.

```
def bar(row: pd.Series):
    row_temp=row.copy(deep=True)
    row_temp['b'] = '42'
    return row_temp
```

**Complete Code**

```py
import pandas as pd


#Changes df in place -- not like lamda
def foo(row: pd.Series):
    row['b'] = '42'


#Do not change df inplace -- works like lambda
def bar(row: pd.Series):
    row_temp = row.copy(deep=True)
    row_temp['b'] = '42'
    return row_temp


df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
df2['a'] = ['a0', 'a1']
df2['b'] = ['b0', 'b1']

print(df2)

# No change inplace
df_b = df2.apply(bar, axis=1)
print(df2)
# bar function works
print(df_b)

print(df2)
# Changes inplace
df2.apply(foo, axis=1)
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
#df2 before any change
    a   b
0  a0  b0
1  a1  b1

#calling df2.apply(bar, axis=1) not changed df2 inplace
    a   b
0  a0  b0
1  a1  b1

#df_b = df2.apply(bar, axis=1) #bar is working as expected
    a   b
0  a0  42
1  a1  42

#print df2 again to assure it is not changed
    a   b
0  a0  b0
1  a1  b1

#call df2.apply(foo, axis=1) -- as we see foo changed df2 inplace ( to compare with bar)
    a   b
0  a0  42
1  a1  42
```